# How do I break out loops with a keyboard input in Python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

All this below is the context for the main program, could mostly be ignored if you change it around

```
    from random import randint
    from time import sleep
    import cursor
    numbers = 0
    random = 0
    mini = 0
    maxi = 0
    nums = list()
    cursor.show()
    while True:
        try:
            miniRange = int(input("Enter the Lower Range: "))
            maxiRange = int(input("Enter the Maxium Range: "))
            if miniRange > maxiRange:
                print("Minium number is higher than Maxium number!")
            elif miniRange < maxiRange and maxiRange > miniRange:
                break
        except:
            print("Error! Not a number!")
    while True:
        try:
            finder = int(input(f"Enter the number you want to find between {miniRange} and {maxiRange}: "))
            if finder < miniRange:
                print(f"Not valid! Lower than {miniRange}!")
            elif finder > maxiRange:
                print(f"Not valid! Higher than {maxiRange}!")
            elif finder >= miniRange and finder <= maxiRange:
                print("--------------------------------------")
                break
        except:
            print("Error! Not a number!")
    cursor.hide()
```

This is the loop I want to break out of, I've tried while x != "" and I've tried importing keyboard but I couldn't find a solution

```
while True:
    try:
        random = randint(miniRange, maxiRange)  
        numbers += 1
        nums.append(random)
        print(random)
        if random == finder:
            mini = min(nums)
            maxi = max(nums)
            print(f"\nIt took {numbers} Tries to find {finder}!")
            print(f"\nThe lowest number found is! {mini}")
            print(f"\nThe highest number found is! {maxi}")
            print("--------------------------------------\n")
            numbers = 0
            nums.clear()
            sleep(5)
    except:
        print("You messed up in a great capacity")
```

Comment: What would be the ending condition of that while loop to exit?

Comment: It'd be `break` @AndrewRyan

Comment: for the third while loop, you could just do `while random_number != finder`

Comment: Thats just kinda the same thing. I basically need something to listen in the background for a key press, then it'll reset the variables and ask again for the inputs before running again @AndrewRyan

Comment: why don't you just wrap all of your code (minus the imports) in a while loop? that will allow you to run the code again. otherwise you can use this to try and exit the loop with a keyboard interrupt https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-kill-a-while-loop-with-a-key-stroke-in-python#:~:text=Use%20KeyboardInterrupt%20to%20kill%20a,the%20while%20loop%20will%20terminate.

Comment: Thats just what I was looking for, Thanks! @AndrewRyan